# find solution in other forms of diffrential equation

Tags: differential-equations

How can I get solution of this differential equation in form of tanh (not tan)

```
DSolve[{x - x f[x, y]^2 == Exp[ y ] D[( f[x, y] /Exp[y]), y]}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Comment: `DSolve[{x - x f[x, y]^2 == Exp[y] D[(f[x, y]/Exp[y]), y]}, 
   f[x, y], {x, y}] /. Sqrt[x_] :> I Sqrt[-x] /. 
 Tan[x_] :> Tan@Expand@x`.

Answer (score 2):

```
DSolve[{x - x f[x, y]^2 == Exp[y] D[(f[x, y]/Exp[y]), y]}, 
  f[x, y], {x, y}];

Assuming[-(1/2) < x < 1/2, FullSimplify[%]]
(* {{f[x, y] -> (
   1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 x^2] Tanh[1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 x^2] (-y + C[1][x])])/(
   2 x)}} *)
```